# How to make the last item grow only when it's wrapped to the next row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a flex container with `flex-wrap:wrap` set. Is there a way to make **the last flex item** (the Unknown button in the example) fill up the remaining space **only when it's wrapped to a new row**? It shouldn't be growing when it's not wrapped to the next line.

Right now I'm setting `flex: 1000 1 0` to the previous item, and `flex:1` to the last item. I wonder if there is any solution that prevents using a large flex grow difference, especially I might want to remove flex grow for the input box based on some media query.

```css
.ut_text {
  min-width: 150px!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="m-2 border border-primary" style="width:300px; resize:horizontal; overflow:hidden;">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap" style="flex: 1000 1 0;">
      <input type="text" placeholder="I am placeholder" class="form-control ut_text"/>
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <a class="form-control btn btn-dark">
              Search
            </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="input-group-append" style="flex: 1;">
      <a class="form-control btn btn-outline-danger">Unknown</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Note that the solution shouldn't depend on the properties of the container, its width/overflow/resize is set just for demonstration purpose.)

Comment: which block do you need to fill after the wrapping? "Search" btn?

Comment: So your code works as intended but you don't like it?

Comment: Yes! It seems like a bad solution.

Comment: your question will turn "opinion based" because there is no real issue. It looks bad for you but for me it's "good" since it "works". Any working solution can looks either good or bad, it's subjective.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this flex rules for your items in flexbox container, it will do the trick: flex-grow to 1, flex-shrink to 0, and flex-basis to auto, shortcut is here:

```
.flex-item {
   flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

then you can remove your inline styles, codepen is here: https://codepen.io/unsleeping/pen/oNVzYdL

Comment: This is not working. The expected result should be the same as the example I've provided above. I'm just looking for an alternative solution.

Comment: your example and my codepen are looking the same, what am i missing?

Comment: Hmm I might not be explaining well enough. This solution will cause the last item to always be wrapped to the next line.

Comment: @SyndRain The confusion is more on "only when it's wrapped to a new row". This isn't clear to me whether you need the last item wrapped to the next line or in the same row.

Comment: Note that `flex-wrap:wrap` is set (by bootstrap `input-group` class) and by default the buttons are not shrinking/growing. This means that when the width of the container is smaller than the 150px+`min-content` width of both buttons, the last item will be wrapped. Before that happened I don't want the buttons to grow.

Comment: https://codepen.io/unsleeping/pen/oNVzYdL this is what you need? try to play with rezising, when there is less than 300px it will wrap and fill the full row

Comment: No that is not. As you can see when nothing is wrapped, in your example all three items are growing at the same time. I only want the RED one to grow. Others should remain the same size.

Comment: now I understand the conditions, is it possible to use js here?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! No I want to avoid using JS.

Comment: how about media queries? i would like to have a trigger in css to understand that wrapping happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256546/discussion-between-unsleeping-and-syndrain).